# Android development with sqlite: query result shouldn't be empty

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a rather big query that is returning data when executed outside android while returning nothing when executed within android.

- I split the query in several pieces and determined that the union was ok.
- I tried on a smaller set of data with the same behavior.
- I've tested with different hardware and API versions.
- I'm using the rawQuery method with constant values.
  [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

This query was meant to replace a FULL OUTER JOIN which is not currently supported.

```
SELECT IFNULL(stype, gtype) AS type, IFNULL(sdate, gdate) AS date, IFNULL(sroute, groute) AS route FROM (

SELECT sp.type AS stype, sp.date AS sdate, -1 AS gtype, gp.date AS gdate, sp.route AS sroute, gp.route AS groute
FROM Sensor_Point AS sp LEFT JOIN GPS_Point AS gp ON gp._id IS NULL AND sp.sent=0 AND sp.route=gp.route AND sp.route=1
UNION ALL
SELECT sp.type AS stype, sp.date AS sdate, -1 AS gtype, gp.date AS gdate, sp.route AS sroute, gp.route AS groute
FROM GPS_Point AS gp LEFT JOIN Sensor_Point AS sp ON sp._id IS NULL AND gp.sent=0 AND sp.route=gp.route AND gp.route=1

) WHERE route=1 ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 255
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Look's like the problem is finally with the query parameters, if I set it this way:

```
String[] args = new String[3];
args[0] = args[1] = args[2] = "1"; 
Cursor data dataBase.rawQuery(SELECT_POINTS, args);
```

It doesn't work, while it works when hardcoding values directly in the query.

```
Cursor data = dataBase.rawQuery(SELECT_POINTS, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android database API, all query parameters are strings.
(This is a horrible design mistake.)

Your query corresponds to:

```
... AND sp.route='1'
```

Try to convert the parameter strings back into a number like this:

```
... AND sp.route = CAST(? AS INT)
```

or just put the number directly into the query string.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CL. this is it !! I first thought the problem was related to the nested query because the subquery was working fine without any casting, but I was wrong.